# What is the best way to copy only certain values from every object in array into another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

Because the Bootstrap Vue Form Select element uses the 'text' and 'value' values of objects in an array, I want to create a new array from an existing array with objects that each contain several values. I need to copy two of these values ('id' and 'msg') from every object in my existing array, and create objects of the same index in my new array, using the values from 'id' and 'msg' to populate their 'text' and 'value' values. What is the best way to do this?

This is what I came up with:

```
selectoptions(){
  var options = [];
  for (var i in this.proposals) {
    options[i] = { value: this.proposals[i].id, text: this.proposals[i].msg};
  }
  return options;
}
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this, possibly using Array.prototype.map.

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.map`. Also, it is always helpful to show us some example data and what you've actually tried.

Comment: Updated my post. Could you please explain how I can use Array.prototype.map for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If proposals is an object then do this:

```
const result = Object.keys(this.proposals).map((key) => ({
    value: this.proposals[key].id,
    text: this.proposals[key].proposal
}))
```

If proposals is an array

```
   const result = this.proposals.map((currentProposal) => ({
        value: currentProposal.id,
        text: currentProposal.proposal
    }))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a *pick* function to pick only the desired properties from an object, passing the required mapping from the existing object(s) to the new one(s). We can use Object.entries, then filter and Object.fromEntries to do this.

For example:

```js
    let a = [{ 
        id: 1,
        msg: 'Some msg 1',
        data: 'Some data'
    },
    { 
        id: 2,
        msg: 'Some msg 2',
        data: 'Some data'
    },
    { 
        id: 3,
        msg: 'Some msg 3',
        data: 'Some data'
    },
]

function pick(obj, propertyMapping) {
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
      if (propertyMapping[key]) { 
        acc.push([propertyMapping[key], value]);
      }
      return acc
  } , []));
}

console.log(a.map((el) => pick(el, { id: "value", msg: "text" } )));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the work:

```
this.proposals = this.proposals.map(el => {
    return {value:el.id, text: el.msg}
});
```

You can [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the documentation of `Array.map` function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mapping to a new array, you could also use your existing array.
`b-select` allows you to write `b-select-option` inside its tags which will be used as options.
So you can create a `v-for` with your existing array and add the `id` as value and `msg` as the text inside `b-select-option`.

If you need the whole object when selecting a value, you can also pass that into the value property and the v-model of the select will return the entire object.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      selected: null,
      selected2: null,
      messages: [
        { id: 1, msg: 'This is message 1', user: 'Hiws' },
        { id: 2, msg: 'This is message 2', user: 'Hiws' },
        { id: 3, msg: 'This is message 3', user: 'Hiws' }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.5.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.5.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="app">
  <!-- Example 1 -->
  <h3>v-model is the only the id</h3>
  <b-select v-model="selected" class="mb-3">
    <b-select-option v-for="{ id, msg } in messages" :key="id" :value="id">
     {{ msg }}
    </b-select-option>
  </b-select>
  Selected value: {{ selected }}
  
  <hr />

  <!-- Example 2 -->
  <h3>v-model is the entire object</h3>
  <b-select v-model="selected2" class="mb-3">
    <b-select-option v-for="message in messages" :key="message.id" :value="message">
     {{ message.msg }}
    </b-select-option>
  </b-select>
  Selected value: {{ selected2 }}
</div>
```

Comment: Love this solution, it looks to be the best way to go :) Thank you